# log4j2 rolled file name

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

Is there a way to get rolled file name? I wrote custom plugin that signals file rolling but I need to get file name of rolled file. My plugin is signaled from java code:

Custom plugin:

```
@Plugin(name = "RTriggerPolicy", category = "Core", printObject = true)
public class RTriggerPolicy implements TriggeringPolicy {
    //...
    @Override
    public boolean isTriggeringEvent(LogEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof RLogEvent)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    //...
}
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<RollingFile name="appFile" fileName="${dir}app.log" append="true" filePattern="${dir}${roll}app-%d{yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.log">
    <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
    <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
    <Policies>
        <RTriggerPolicy name="app"/>
    </Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get the rolled file name would be to extend DefaultRolloverStrategy and override the rollover method. You would then implement that as:

```
@Override
public RolloverDescription rollover(final RollingFileManager manager) throws SecurityException {
    RolloverDescription rolloverDescription = super.rollover(manager);
    if (rolloverDescription.getSynchronous instanceof FileRenameAction) {
        File file = ((FileRenameAction) rolloverDescription.getSynchronous()).getDestination();
        // Do something useful here.
    }
}
```